# How to highlight, for one second, an entire row

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, dom, css-selectors

I'm coming from a jquery background where selectors are easy to use. What I want to do is for the first children of a tbody (there's only one table) I want to highlight for a second the entire row. I tried with css `:first-child` selector on the tr but I don't know why it didn't work. Is there a way of doing this on the scripting side? with vue.js selecting the element? because it does not add any id to the elements (as some other frameworks like Django would do). Here is my template:

```
<v-container v-else grid-list-xl>
      <v-data-table
        :disable-initial-sort="true"
        :rows-per-page-items="[10, 20, 30]"
        :headers="headers"
        :items="data_table"
        class="elevation-1"
      >
        <template v-if="loading" v-slot:no-data>
          <v-alert :value="true" color="warning" icon="warning">
            Trayendo datos del gateway, porfa esperate...
          </v-alert>
        </template>
        <template v-else v-slot:items="props">
          <td><strong>{{ props.item.time }}</strong></td>
          <td>{{ props.item.A }}</td>
          <td>{{ props.item.B }}</td>
          <td>{{ props.item.C }}</td>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
  </v-container>
```

This would be because I get a new row on the table every minute or so, and I want the user to be able to easily see that new data was added. Here is the css I was trying:

```
  tr :first-child {
    color: red;
    background-image:none !important; 
        -o-animation: fadeIt 5s ease-in-out; 
           animation: fadeIt 5s ease-in-out; 
  };

  @-o-keyframes fadeIt {
    0%   { background-color: #FFFFFF; }
    50%  { background-color: #AD301B; }
    100% { background-color: #FFFFFF; }
  }
  @keyframes fadeIt {
    0%   { background-color: #FFFFFF; }
    50%  { background-color: #AD301B; }
    100% { background-color: #FFFFFF; }
  }
```

Comment: use `tr:first-child` without space

Comment: try to use:`.v-datatable tbody tr:first-child {}` as my example:https://codepen.io/leenmalka/pen/MMBbJw

Comment: and maybe add `infinite` to animation:https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation.asp

Comment: @לבנימלכה I don't know why it works on your end but not on mine. It's really weird. Note that if I change the element from the tr to td it shows the animation on every first td element. So the problem is on the selector, but it's really weird indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Apparently if you don't explicitly add a `tr` element on your html code (even though it gets added on the DOM) the selector won't work. That's why I only needed to add a `tr` to wrap every `td`.

I know that this is some basic HTML markup but I thought that if it appeared on the DOM it would work anyways, but it did not. This is my working code now:

```
<v-container grid-list-xl>
      <v-data-table
        :disable-initial-sort="true"
        :rows-per-page-items="[10, 20, 30]"
        :headers="headers"
        :items="data_table"
        class="elevation-1"
      >
        <template v-if="loading" v-slot:no-data>
          <v-alert :value="true" color="warning" icon="warning">
            Trayendo datos del gateway, porfa esperate...
          </v-alert>
        </template>
        <template v-else v-slot:items="props">
          <tr>
            <td><strong>{{ props.item.time }}</strong></td>
            <td>{{ props.item.A }}</td>
            <td>{{ props.item.B }}</td>
            <td>{{ props.item.C }}</td>
          </tr>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
  </v-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added unneeded space in `tr : first-child`.

```css
tr:first-child {
  color: red;
  background-image: none;
  -o-animation: fadeIt 5s ease-in-out;
  animation: fadeIt 5s ease-in-out;
}

;
@-o-keyframes fadeIt {
  0% {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #AD301B;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIt {
  0% {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #AD301B;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>1</strong></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>1</strong></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Look at this [solution](https://codepen.io/eyalcohen4/pen/orMzBb):

Comment: should be a comment!!

Comment: @לבנימלכה No, anything that tries to answer the question at hand should be an answer. This seems to try to answer the question, so it is fine where it is.

Comment: It doesn't work either. I don't know if it is because the template doesn't have a tr element per se, but it rather gets added by vue v-slot and that causes the problem. Perhaps I need to deal with this on the scripting side.

Comment: show me the new link(when you save new link create)

Comment: The code isn't working, codesandbox.io may be suited for this one. 
Please try top upload your code there and make sure it's running, or write down what not working for you.